# How to Display Uploaded Document Link to View/Download in InfoPath Form?

Tags: list, infopath, document, forms-services

Hello I am new to Infopath! 
I have Two Share point Lists:

**1. ClientList(ClientID,ClientName,Title,ID)**

**2. ClientDocuments(DocumentID,RelatedClient,DocumentName,Title,ID etc)**

**RelatedClient** field has **LookUp** Value which refers **"Title"** Field from **ClientList**

I have populated ClientList using Client DataSource Connection which displays ClientNames and have Inserted Repeated section(data section) from ClientDocuments Data Connection.

On selection of DropDownList which contains ClientNames the Repeating Section display Document Names Related to that Specific Client.

***Now, I want to Display the Documents in Repeating Section of InfoPath Form and allow Users to View/Download the Document.***

Help Appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need InfoPath in this case? I think you should go another way - customize the display/edit form of ClientList in the browser to add a web part of related list (Client documents). That approach should be more upgrade-compatible.